# Check for this error during Python minimalmodbus communication test

Tags: raspberry-pi3, python-3.9, rs485, minimalmodbus

Test Model : raspberry PI 3 (RPI3)

USB TO RS485 ( FT232 )

Temperature/hygrometer (24V)

CODE:

```
import minimalmodbus as minimalmodbus
import serial,time
import serial.tools.list_ports as sp

for i in range(len(sp.comports())):
    desc = sp.comports()[i].description
    if desc.find('USB2.0') != -1:
        port = sp.comports()[i].device
        break
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # /dev/ttyUSB0
    
    instrument = minimalmodbus.Instrument('/dev/ttyUSB0', 2)
    instrument.serial.baudrate = 9600  # Baud
    instrument.serial.bytesize = 8
    instrument.serial.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
    instrument.serial.stopbits = 1
    instrument.address = 2
    instrument.mode = minimalmodbus.MODE_RTU
    instrument.serial.timeout = 1  # seconds
    instrument.clear_buffers_before_each_transaction = True
    # instrument.debug = True
    instrument.precalculate_read_size = True
    
    # instrument.serial.
    # instrument.serial.close()
    while True:
        
        try:
            print(instrument.read_register(0,functioncode=4))
        # temp1 = instrument.read_bit(30033,)
        # temp2 = instrument.read_register(1,functioncode= int('0x04',16))
        
        # print(temp2)
        # time.sleep(10)
        
    
        # temp1 = instrument.read_register(0,functioncode= int('0x04',16))

        except minimalmodbus.InvalidResponseError:
            print('checksum error')
            continue
                    
    # except IOError as e:
    #     print("Failed to read from instrument",e)
```

FIND ERR0R T0 dmesg:

```
[312355.728463] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_write_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
```

```
[312356.734082] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_write_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
```

```
[312357.739717] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_write_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
```

```
[312358.745338] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_write_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
```

```
[312359.750962] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: usb_serial_generic_write_bulk_callback - urb stopped: -32
```

At first, normal communication was carried out, but suddenly WRITE_CALLBACK

What is the problem, and what can I do?

sudo nano /boot/cmdline.txt after modifying dwc_otg.speed=1 and trying restart with the same result.